# Building and Separation of Query Logic in Linq /mvc4

Tags: linq, twitter, linq-to-objects, datacontext, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to separate my logic for better readability and re-useability. I am trying to build a better application.

I will show you a sample of a working controller and model and show where I am trying to go.

This is where i am before the conversion.

```
    private IOAuthCredentials credentials = new SessionStateCredentials();
    private MvcAuthorizer auth;
    private TwitterContext twitterCtx;

 public ActionResult Twitter()
    {



        if (credentials.ConsumerKey == null || credentials.ConsumerSecret == null)
        {
            credentials.ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerKey"];
            credentials.ConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerSecret"];
            credentials.OAuthToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterOAuthToken"];
            credentials.AccessToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterAccessToken"];
        }

     auth = new MvcAuthorizer
      {
           Credentials = credentials
       };

       auth.CompleteAuthorization(Request.Url);

       if (!auth.IsAuthorized)
        {
            Uri specialUri = new Uri(Request.Url.ToString());
           return auth.BeginAuthorization(specialUri);
      }





                twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth);

                 List<TweetViewModel> friendTweets = (from tweet in twitterCtx.Status
                                                      where tweet.Type == StatusType.Friends
                                                     select new TweetViewModel
                                                   {
                                                         ImageUrl = tweet.User.ProfileImageUrl,
                                                           ScreenName = tweet.User.Identifier.ScreenName,
                                                          Tweet = tweet.Text
                                                      })
        .ToList();

   return View(friendTweets);
```

here is the class

```
public class TweetViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// User's avatar
    /// </summary>
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// User's Twitter name
    /// </summary>
    public string ScreenName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Text containing user's tweet
    /// </summary>
    public string Tweet { get; set; }
}
```

I made a datacontext folder and put a dataclass in

here is the class

```
  public class TwitterFriend
  {
    private MvcAuthorizer auth;
    public List<TweetViewModel> GetFriends()
    {

      //  private MvcAuthorizer auth;
        using (var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth))
        {

            var friendTweets = (from tweet in twitterCtx.Status
                                                 where tweet.Type == StatusType.Friends
                                                 select new TweetViewModel
                                                 {
                                                     ImageUrl = tweet.User.ProfileImageUrl,
                                                     ScreenName = tweet.User.Identifier.ScreenName,
                                                     Tweet = tweet.Text
                                                 })
            .ToList();

            return friendTweets;
         }
     }
```

Then I tried to make a List method to instantiate the list (does not work)

```
    public List<TweetViewModel> GetFriendTweets()
    {
        List<TweetViewModel> friends = (List<TweetViewModel>)(new TwitterFriend());
        // friends.ToList();

        return friends.ToList();
    }
}
```

Then I would put the pull the list from the method

Getfriends():

Sorry if I pasted alot of stuff, I am trying to design and make a proper app where I dont have to redo my logic all over because I knew I could hit these pitfalls.

Can i get some help fixing this. I dont think this is a complicated scenario.

The amended answer for others if they need help is below!  Thank you!!

Just the dataclass

```
      public List<TweetViewModel> GetFriends()
       //  public List<Status> GetFriends()
        {
        using (var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(_auth))
         {


            // List<Type> 
            List<Status> friendTweets = (from tweet in twitterCtx.Status
                                         where tweet.Type == StatusType.Friends
                                         select tweet).ToList();

            List<TweetViewModel> friends = new List<TweetViewModel>();            

            foreach (Status item in friendTweets)
            {
                TweetViewModel search2 = new TweetViewModel();
                {
                    search2.ImageUrl = item.User.ProfileImageUrl;
                    search2.ScreenName = item.User.Identifier.ScreenName;
                    search2.Tweet = item.Text;
                }
             friends.Add(search2);
            }


            return friends.ToList();
```

Comment: In the part you initialize your `MvcAuthorizer` object. In the `TwitterFriend` class it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a constructor to Twitter friend class where you inject the MVCAuthorizer.

public class TwitterFriendService{

```
private readonly MvcAuthorizer _auth;
public TwitterFriend(MvcAuthorizer auth){

_auth = auth;
}
```

public List GetFriends()
    {

```
    using (var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(_auth))
    {
```

var friendTweets = (from tweet in twitterCtx.Status
                                         where tweet.Type == StatusType.Friends
                                         select new TweetViewModel
                                         {
                                             ImageUrl = tweet.User.ProfileImageUrl,
                                             ScreenName = tweet.User.Identifier.ScreenName,
                                             Tweet = tweet.Text
                                         })
    .ToList();

```
    return friendTweets;
 }
```

}

and then on the controller:

```
private IOAuthCredentials credentials = new SessionStateCredentials();
    private MvcAuthorizer auth;
    private TwitterContext twitterCtx;

 public ActionResult Twitter()
    {



        if (credentials.ConsumerKey == null || credentials.ConsumerSecret == null)
        {
            credentials.ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerKey"];
            credentials.ConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerSecret"];
            credentials.OAuthToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterOAuthToken"];
            credentials.AccessToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterAccessToken"];
        }

     auth = new MvcAuthorizer
      {
           Credentials = credentials
       };

       auth.CompleteAuthorization(Request.Url);

       if (!auth.IsAuthorized)
        {
            Uri specialUri = new Uri(Request.Url.ToString());
           return auth.BeginAuthorization(specialUri);
      }



    TwitterFriendService twitterFriendService = new TwitterFriendService(auth);
    List<TweetViewModel> friendTweets = twitterFriendService.GetFriends();

       return View(friendTweets);
```

}

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you soo much, I am getting this error in the service context Error 1 Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<UnityDITest.Models.TweetViewModel>' to 'LinqToTwitter.List' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion

Comment: it seems you are mixing 2 different objects. The one returned by the Linq query : from tweet in twitterCtx.Statuswhere tweet.Type == StatusType.Friends. Can you post the code where that's happening?

Comment: In the data class public List GetFriends() {

    using (var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(_auth))
    {

var friendTweets = (from tweet in twitterCtx.Status where tweet.Type == StatusType.Friends select new TweetViewModel { ImageUrl = tweet.User.ProfileImageUrl, ScreenName = tweet.User.Identifier.ScreenName, Tweet = tweet.Text }) .ToList();

    return friendTweets;   <- return  i cant cast it either
 }

}

Comment: Get the list first without transforming it to TweetViewModel. Then create an empty list (List<TweetViewModel>) and do a foreach inserting a new TweetViewModel into the new list. Somehow your are messing up the types. try that way and then if it works you can refactor.

Comment: Can you point me in a direction so i can see how its done.  I put a breakpoint in and casted it return (List)((IEnumerable<Status>)friendTweets);  no errors till i run it but the data loaded in the query. i like the 2nd query approach too cuz i can keep the results and do more i wanted to add more properties

Comment: List<Type> friendTweets = (from tweet in twitterCtx.Status where tweet.Type== StatusType.Friends).ToList();
List<TweetViewModel> friends = new List<TweetViewModel>(); foreach(Type item in friendTweets){ TweetViewModel newItem = new TweetViewModel(); newItem.field = item.field => do this for all fields . friends.add(newItem); } return friends;   => hope this helps

Comment: while i understand the direct your trying to show me, the first query isnt allowed, i even tried different things. could it be i need to change the public list GetFriend to a different object

Comment: i wired it all up and got the objects working and still the same error. go figure

Comment: Holy Crap I got it, I had to make some changes.      had to use public List<TweetViewModel> GetFriends() and

                return friends.ToList();